# R zoo aggregate

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo object containing the following data :

```
                          Qty 
2013-11-25 12:41:21.33       2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22.25      2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22.75      75 
2013-11-25 12:41:24.22      3 
2013-11-25 12:41:25.22      1 
2013-11-25 12:41:26.22      1
```

I want to aggregate it by second, summing the values inside each second AND ALSO putting a quantity to zero for the seconds that are not in the sample, so that I have the following regular series

```
                          Qty 
2013-11-25 12:41:21         2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22        77 
2013-11-25 12:41:23        0 
2013-11-25 12:41:24        3 
2013-11-25 12:41:25        1 
2013-11-25 12:41:26        1
```

Notice the third row (trying to use aggregate as explained in the vignette, with a function that transforms original time stamps to get rid of millisecond precision fails in appearing that third row and in having a regular series)

I tried, thanks to answer below :

if a is my original zoo series

```
b=aggregate(a,by=cut(as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(index(a))),origin="1970-01-01"‌​), breaks='1 sec'),FUN=sum)
```

But that gives 
                          Qty
    2013-11-25 12:41:21    2 
    2013-11-25 12:41:22    77 
    2013-11-25 12:41:24    3 
    2013-11-25 12:41:25    1 
    2013-11-25 12:41:26    1

So without the row

```
2013-11-25 12:41:23    0
```

which makes the series regular and which is the point of my question
Thanks a lot for help

Comment: Aggregate by `cut(as.POSIXct(index(...)), breaks='1 sec')`.

Comment: Thanks.. That does not give integer seconds if my data begins by a non integer second.. Can you write the entire command?

Comment: Isn't there a `trunc` method? I don't answer questions posed with screen output from zoo objects. I'm planning to ask a question about automatic input of such. Maybe someone will answer. Life is too short to mess around getting the properly input. If you want me to play, I need dput() output.

Comment: Thanks.. Indeed the solution does not work. I tweaked it a little to give integer seconds : if a is my original zoo series

       b=aggregate(a,by=cut(as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(index(a))),,origin="1970-01-01"), breaks='1 sec'),FUN=sum)

gives

                             Qty 
    2013-11-25 12:41:21         2 
    2013-11-25 12:41:22        77 
    2013-11-25 12:41:24        3 
    2013-11-25 12:41:25        1 
2013-11-25 12:41:26        1

So without the row 2013-11-25 12:41:23        0 , which makes the series regular and which is the point of my quesyion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read in the test data, aggregate it by seconds and then merge the aggregated series with a grid to fill it in:

```
# read test data

Lines <- "2013-11-25 12:41:21         2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22.25      2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22.75      75 
2013-11-25 12:41:24.22      3 
2013-11-25 12:41:25.22      1 
2013-11-25 12:41:26.22      1"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2, tz = "")

# aggregate and merge with grid to fill it out 

ag <- aggregate(z, as.POSIXct(trunc(time(z), "sec")), sum)
g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "sec"))
merge(ag, g, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Yet another terse and elegant solution, GG. I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why my experience with `read.zoo` is so different. Probably something to do with not understanding the defaults or options for the `tz` attribute.

Comment: In the latest version of zoo on CRAN `read.zoo` will check if the input date or date/time is of the form yyyy-mm-dd or yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS and use Date class or POSIXct class (with local time zone) in the first and second cases.  If input is of any other form or you want any other index class you need to specify it via appropriate arguments, typically the `FUN=` argument.  Thus, in this example, its now possible to omit the `tz = ""` argument.and just write `read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2)`

Comment: I have a dataset which is using nanotime and having zoo time as nanoseconds ag <- aggregate(z, nanotime(trunc(time(z), "sec")), sum)
Error in trunc(time(z), "sec") : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function